# IsTouching and OverlapCollider contradicting each other?

Tags: unity-game-engine, top-down

From a top down perspective I am trying to make it so that a player can fall into a pit. I want to use 2DCircleCollider.IsTouching(ContactFilter2D) to check whether the players hitbox overlaps with the ground but this always returns false despite OverlapCollider fuctioning correctly with the same contactfilter. My character has a rigidbody attatched and the ground does not. Are these two functions fundamentally different or am I using IsTouching wrong?

EDIT

```
public class CollisionChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CircleCollider2D p1Box;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    //public LayerMask Iceberg;
    public ContactFilter2D cf2d;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        p1Box = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int debugcount = 0;

        Collider2D\[\] results = new Collider2D\[100\];
        p1Box.OverlapCollider(cf2d, results);
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
        {
            if (results\[i\] != null)
            {
                debugcount++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log(debugcount);
        Debug.Log(p1Box.IsTouching(cf2d));
        debugcount = 0;
        //if (!rb2d.IsTouchingLayers(Iceberg))
        //{
        //    Debug.Log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
        //}
    }
}
```

[player object with inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1TXx.png)

[ground tile with inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH3uh.png)

Comment: If you have problems with IsTouching show how you're using it. Without that code it's hard to help. It would be helpful if you also provide two screenshot of the "Inspector" tab that shows what's attached to those two objects you want to check if they are touching

Comment: I've attached my code and two objects which are overlapping, at this point in the screenshot the console says that 9 tiles are ColliderOverlapping but IsTouching is false using the same contact filter

Comment: I've seen instances where the scale of a 2D affects `IsTouching`. The default scale is 1,1,1. Usually, you shouldn't go under this. It confuses the physics system. You can check if this is the issue by re-sizing it,